# Successfully compiled chromium browser on Ubuntu 14.04. What now?

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium

I have successfully compiled **chromium browser** on Ubuntu 14.04 using the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/chrome/src
ninja -C out/Debug chrome
```

My problem is that I do not exactly know how to verify my code if I make any changes to the actual one.

Test case:

- let's suppose that I will try to add a piece of code into `chrome/browser/ui/browser.cc` for some [**Tab startup & initial navigation**](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code)

All of the compiling process took about 5 hours to complete, after many headaches with some dependencies.

**My questions**:

- I will have to compile all of those files again when I make some changes to `browser.cc` or just compile `browser.cc` instead ? If it's the last one, can you suggest the best command to do this ?
- After the previous step is completed, how will I actually be able to see the changes I've made ? ( sort of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in Visual Studio to see the browser UI with that changes ). I would also like a command for doing this.
- And the last question: can you guys suggest me an IDE for the entire Chromium Project ( Ubuntu 14.04 ), from your own experience ?

Documentation that I followed in order to learn things about chromium browser project:

**1. [getting-around-the-chrome-source-code](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code)

2. [displaying-a-web-page-in-chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/displaying-a-web-page-in-chrome)

3. [multi-process-architecture](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture)

4. [design-documents](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents)

5. [build-instructions-using-ninja](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/NinjaBuild)**

Comment: How about trying? Usually the build process will only compile the modified files and link them to what is needed. And to try it? Run the executable.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Can you be more specific ? To try what ? I can make the modifications but how to link them to what is needed ? How to run the executable ? What about the other questions ?

Comment: You already know how to compile, so after making changes, compile again. And if you don't know how to run an executable in a Linux environment, how will you do any development?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Please, follow my questions exactly. I will have to compile all the files or just the edited ones ? I know how to run an executable, but where is located this executable and which is the one that I have to execute :) ?

Comment: As I said, the build system will handle the things for you. Just try it. Modify a file. Run the compilation again. You will see what happens. You don't have to go on hunting for modified files yourself. The binary will be in `out/Debug` directory and named `chrome`, as the documentation says. Software suggestions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: SamiKuhmonen has actually answered you but you may not have understood. To be explicit: just run the `ninja` command again. It will take care of compiling/linking whatever is needed (it won't re-do everything). The executable will be in `out/Debug` as that is where you have told the build to place it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I will try this out and come with an answer. Any IDE that you recommend for this project ? I actually have QT Creator installed on my Ubuntu machine

Comment: It worked. You can add your comment as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks

Comment: @Alexander: can you see my issue here. i am trying to modify the UI but no help is coming from anywhere yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989846/google-chrome-from-which-source-file-i-can-change-the-gui